# Вводить один символ использовать для вывода как первый, но каждый следующий увеличивать на один

Tags: c

код выводитна экран заданный символ в форме
прямоугольного треугольника нужно подправит код так чтобы (один символ использовать для вывода как первый, но каждый следующий увеличивать на один.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{

    char c;
    printf("\n Input character ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("\n%c\n%c%c\n%c %c\n%c  %c\n%c   %c\n%c%c%c%c%c%c", c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сдается мне тут задание на цикл, а не на хитрость с printf...

Comment: нужно с printf  с циклом не принимают

Comment: Ну значит c+1 где-то надо использовать.

Comment: И на чем остановиться? Какого размера треугольник?

Comment: Явный пример ввода, вывода в вопрос добавьте для ясности.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = 'c';
printf("  %c \n %c %c \n%c %c %c ",c, c, c, c, c, c );
```

Треугольник со стороной три. Советую строить сначала на листе по линиям, чтобы представить, как будет `printf` это всё выводить + строить треугольник в две стороны, начиная с вершины.

Comment: Это контрпродуктивно, вам предложили циклом воспользоваться. У K&R как раз в главе по циклам идет рисование всяких фигур, ЕМНИП.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, у него с циклом не принимают.